# azure machine learning studio "execute R script" is unable to load ggplot2 library from scriptbundle.zip

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Rscript:

install.packages("src/Rpackages/Rcpp.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
library(Rcpp, lib.loc=".", verbose=TRUE) 
install.packages("src/Rpackages/ggplot2_2.2.1.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
library(ggplot2, lib.loc=".", verbose=TRUE)

Error :

requestId = 2719717d8d5b4a479547886c19b0bcb4 errorComponent=Module. taskStatusCode=400. {"Exception":{"ErrorId":"FailedToEvaluateRScript","ErrorCode":"0063","ExceptionType":"ModuleException","Message":"Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:\r\n---------- Start of error message from R ----------\r\npackage or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2'\r\n\r\n\r\npackage or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2'\r\n----------- End of error message from R -----------"}}Error: Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:---------- Start of error message from R ----------package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2'package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2'----------- End of error message from R ----------- Process exited with error code -2

[azuremlstudio snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDbHN.png)

Comment: [Please Read How to Ask on Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

why are you trying to install ggplot2 when it is already included in Azure ML? just simply reference it in your R code.